# Flask jsonify boolean response cannot be decoded in unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am performing tests on my Flask application and I am expecting a json response built with `jsonify`. I use the `ast` library to decode the response. But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_index.py", line 177, in test_create_venue
    data = ast.literal_eval(rv.data)
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

My test function is as follows:

```
def test_create_venue(self):
    rv = self.app.get("/data_send")
    data = ast.literal_eval(rv.data)
    self.assertTrue(data["Sent"])
```

And the application's function is:

```
@app.route('/data_send', methods = ['GET'])
def data_send():
    usr = User.get_by_id(g.user.key.id())
    usr.get_last_order().set_as_posted()
    rest = usr.restaurant
    for c in rest.channel_set():
        try:
            channel.send_message(c.cid, 'ping')
        except:
            return jsonify(Sent = False)
    return jsonify(Sent = True)
```

Jsonify is sending the following response:

```
'{\n  "Sent": true\n}'
```

But `ast` does not recognize the lower case `true` as Boolean. Hence, it raises a `ValueError`.

Any idea how to transform `jsonify`'s response into a `Dict` that maintains the Boolean value so I can perform the Boolean assertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `literal_eval` to load JSON.  Ever.

Use [Flask's JSON decoder](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.loads), or the [app-specific decoder](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.json_decoder).

```
from flask import json
data = json.loads(rv.data)
# or
self.app.json_decoder.decode(rv.data)
```

Or if you're not using Flask, and need to load JSON, use the [built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

```
import json
data = json.loads(json_data)
```